# Optaplanner - continuous planning with changing constraints, that do not set prior assignments invalid

Tags: optaplanner

we are using Optaplanner 7.0 beta + Graphhopper for a calculation of shortest paths in a warehouse, where goods have to be collected into boxes by workers (vrptw). Since the business is about collecting online-ordered goods approx. 70% of the items to collect are added to the problem during the day. We use ProblemFactChange to add the incoming order items and already completed order items in the chain are set to immovable (these 'restarts' are performed each full hour). So far everything works.

The question now is about changing restrictions/conditions, that can occur due to unbalanced workload over warehouse-zones. The warehouse is logically divided into areas, to avoid that all workers have to serve all areas (I know your opinion about segmentation of planning problems, but this is, how the work currently is organised). The limited assignment of items to available workers within one zone is currently defined by a hard-constraint.

The new requirement that we are confronted with is, that a worker should be temporary assigned to a different zone, if the workload there is higher compared to his actual zone. Afterwards he can switch back to his original zone. To my understanding an update of the constraint condition would result in hard constraint violations for the previous assigned, locked items, which should be avoided. Are there mechanisms to support temporary changing restrictions or would a SelectionFilter for items help ? (btw: we are using drools).

Hints are welcome, Thank you 
Michael

Comment: Perhaps just modify scoring so that immovable items don't affect it?

Comment: Thank you for the proposals. Meanwhile we excluded immovable entities from scoring and it works as supposed !

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 different *tenants*, each with their own set of employees, tasks, etc and each in their own Solver, then the **Borrow Pattern** can be used, especially if the employee borrowing involves some human interaction (usually paperwork or a phone call between managers):

Suppose tenant A has an employee called John and tenant B wants to borrow him. Then assign one or more entities from B to John and make them *immovable* (usually a `boolean borrowLocked`). Then add the same entities to tenant A. Neither the solver of A nor B will be able to move them (so they won't change), but both of them will take them into account: tenant A won't give John work when he's working for tenant B and tenant B will agree that those entities are assigned (and it won't try to assign John to other entities as it's no in it's value range).